# how i convert a bool to a Unityengine.Cursorlockmode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a small script to hide and put a cursor visible and I miss an error that specifically is this

error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `bool' to`UnityEngine.CursorLockMode'

and this is the code

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class yea : MonoBehaviour {
    bool isLocked;
    void Start () {
        SetCursorLock(true);
    }


    void SetCursorLock(bool isLocked)
    {
        this.isLocked = isLocked;
        Cursor.lockState = isLocked;
        Cursor.visible = !isLocked;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            SetCursorLock(!isLocked);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
        {
            SetCursorLock(isLocked);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you want to convert a bool to a CursorLockMode. I think you're expected to have provided a CursorLockMode type to Cursor.lockState.

Answer (score 7):

`Cursor.lockState`  is an enum ([`CursorLockMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CursorLockMode.html)) so you can't assign `bool` to it.

```
void SetCursorLock(bool isLocked)
{
    this.isLocked = isLocked;
    if(this.isLocked)
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }else
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }
    Cursor.visible = !isLocked;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use CursorLockMode instead. You can use CursorLockMode.Locked for locking the cursor. More information is available at
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CursorLockMode.html

Code example:

```
 void SetCursorLock(bool isLocked)
 {
     if(isLocked)
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
     else
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;

     Cursor.visible = !isLocked;
 }
```